# Convert uint64_t to unsigned char serialized[8]

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a `uint64_t`value to a `unsigned char` array. Currently my functions are working with `uint32_t`. But as soon as I try to convert a 64bit value the results are different.

Does somebody see a mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <inttypes.h>

using namespace std;

void serialize_uint64(const uint64_t integer, unsigned char * const serializedInteger);
uint64_t deserialize_uint64(unsigned char * const serializedInteger);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t test64 = 0xFF/*FFFFFFFFFFFFFF;*/;

    unsigned char serialized64[8];
    memset(serialized64, 0x00, sizeof(serialized64));

    serialize_uint64(test64, serialized64);

    printf("%llu = %llu\n", test64, deserialize_uint64(serialized64));

    return 0;
}

void serialize_uint64(const uint64_t integer, unsigned char * const serializedInteger)
{
    serializedInteger[0] = integer >> 56;
    serializedInteger[1] = integer >> 48;
    serializedInteger[2] = integer >> 40;
    serializedInteger[3] = integer >> 32;
    serializedInteger[4] = integer >> 24;
    serializedInteger[5] = integer >> 16;
    serializedInteger[6] = integer >> 8;
    serializedInteger[7] = integer;
}

uint64_t deserialize_uint64(unsigned char * const serializedInteger)
{
    uint64_t converted = 0;

    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[0];
    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[1];
    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[2];
    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[3];
    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[4];
    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[5];
    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[6];
    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[7];
    converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[8];

    return converted; // 4294967295
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `(char*)p=(char*)&n;`

Comment: Little and big endian will bite you when using `(char*)p=(char*)&n;` . Please check if `converted = (converted << 8)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: What is expected value ? what do you obtain ? Have you try using a debugger ?

Comment: In the deserialize_uint64 you are using 9 positions from the array, instead of the 8 positions you used when serializing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), you decode 9 bytes. This:

```
converted = (converted << 8) | serializedInteger[8];
```

should not be there. Notice how the index is `8`, i.e. it acccesses the 9th byte which is not there.